# lftp pget 401 Unauthorized

Tags: cygwin, http-status-code-401, lftp

Yo

I'm trying to download a file from DigitalBlasphemy.com using lftp and pget on cygwin on windows.

Now, the usual route involves logging in to the website via web browser (It asks for username and password).

When I try to use lftp's pget command to download the file, lftp just farts out with "401 Unauthorized". How can I provide the relevant credentials to my command?

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the url of the file you are downloading. 
For example instead of

```
pget https://example.com/directory-structure/filename.ext
```

you have to do

```
pget https://username:password@example.com/directory-structure/filename.ext
```